# git diff between 2 commits show me I deleted and added the same content

Tags: git

```
* d556e92 // added 789 in new line inside file1.txt (HEAD -> master)
* 79fe73c // added 456 in new line inside file1.txt
* 574a673 // added 123 to file1.txt
* c50371c // created file1.txt with no content
```

`file1.txt in`master` branch:

```
123
456
789
```

When I run `git diff 574a673..79fe73c` I expect to see **only**: `+456`. But the output is different:

```
$ git diff 574a673..79fe73c
diff --git a/file1.txt b/file1.txt
index d800886..156626c 100644
--- a/file1.txt
+++ b/file1.txt
@@ -1 +1,2 @@
-123
\ No newline at end of file
+123
+456
\ No newline at end of file
```

**My question:**

Does git tell me that I removed "123" and added "123" in the same commit: `79fe73c`?

Comment: Answer in `No newline at end of file`. You remove `123`, but add `123\newline`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You removed

```
123
```

and replaced it with

```
123\n
```

New line starts **after** line termination symbol, so adding new line actually modifies the one before, because `\n` is appended to it.

Comment: That's why it's better to always add an empty line at the end of your files (and why git is showing the `No newline at end of file` warning if you don't)